# Solving Monomial and Polynomial Python Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am experimenting with classes for the first time, and I wanted to create a program that asks the user for an input a,b, and c, and then solves for x for the equation forms stated in the print statements. However, I am having issues with the class, giving me an error that I am not using the variables in the class, missing the 5 positional arguments. Any help would be amazing, thanks so much.

```
class EquationSolver:
    def MonomialSolver(self,a,b,c,x):
        a = input("Enter Input for a:")
        b = input("Enter Input for b:")
        c = input("Enter input for c:")
        x = (c+b)/a
        print("For the equation in the format ax-b=c, with your values chosen x must equal", x)
    def PolynomialSolver(self,a,b,c,x):
        a = input("Enter Input for a:")
        b = input("Enter Input for b:")
        c = input("Enter input for c:")
        x = (c^2 + b) / a
        print("For the equation in the format sqrt(ax+b) = c, with your values chosen x must equal", x)
    MonomialSolver()
    PolynomialSolver()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is the inputs for the functions. You do not need the self parameter or any other parameter. The functions should run outside the loop. The edited version should loop something like this:

```
class EquationSolver:
    def MonomialSolver():
        # Uses float() to turn input to a number
        a = float(input("Enter Input for a:"))
        b = float(input("Enter Input for b:"))
        c = float(input("Enter input for c:"))
        x = (c+b)/a
        print("For the equation in the format ax-b=c, with your values chosen x must equal", x)
    def PolynomialSolver():
        a = float(input("Enter Input for a:"))
        b = float(input("Enter Input for b:"))
        c = float(input("Enter input for c:"))
        x = (c^2 + b) / a
        print("For the equation in the format sqrt(ax+b) = c, with your values chosen x must equal", x)
EquationSolver.MonomialSolver()
EquationSolver.PolynomialSolver()
```